# What is the best way to get out Git branch problem?

Tags: git

I mistakenly pushed a few commits to the main branch instead of a task branch. And I pushed the same version of the code base to a task branch later. To roll back those commits on the main branch, I run "git revert ..." a few times to roll back those commits as I aren't allow to run

```
git push -f origin main
```

after

```
got rest --hard <commit-hash>
```

on the main branch. Now, the main branch is ahead of the task branch. And the person, who is going to do the merge, doesn't want to run some additional commands to merge the branch to the main branch, but directly merge on the Git server.

What is a good way to make the main branch before the task branch but not let the main branch override changes? (Running the "git pull origin main" will remove all changes in the task branch)

Comment: See [Rewriting History](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History) in the Git Book.

Comment: I see, you're not allowed to force push (also [use --force-with-lease instead](https://blog.developer.atlassian.com/force-with-lease/)). You can ask someone who is allowed to do an interactive rebase and remove your bad commits and their reverse. On your end, make sure `main` is up to date and rebase, not merge, your task branch on top of main: `git rebase main`. This will rewrite your branch's commits on top of main and should avoid any issues from those changes having been reverted in main.

Comment: It's unclear what state your repository is in. Would you `git fetch origin` to make sure you're up to date and then provide the relevant parts of `git log --graph --decorate --oneline --all` please?

Comment: Thanks @Schwern for your info. I take the simplest solution, `rebase`. Hopefully, the person won't have any difficulty of merging the branch.

Comment: Thanks again. The command `rebase` likely didn't solve the problem. Someone else pushed a commit to the task branch without overriding the code base.

Comment: That `git log` command I mentioned will help us understand the state of the repo.

Comment: I use both 'git log' and 'git reflog' to check the situation.